# How to enable Bundle transformation without combining files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

In the ASP.NET MVC project I'm working on there're two application keys relative to the bundling process: `AppKeys.ApplyMinifyingTransformation` shows whether `.css` and `.js` files should be minified and combined, `AppKeys.ApplyStaticFilesTransformations` shows whether some file content transformations should be applied. Different combinations of these flags are to be used on different stages. Here is a simplified version of the `RegisterBundles` method:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = AppKeys.ApplyMinifyingTransformationAndBlockJs || 
            AppKeys.ApplyStaticFilesTransformations;
    var lessStyles = new Bundle("~/Bundles/Styles/")
        .IncludeDirectory("~/Path-to-css", "*.css", true);
    var postProcessors = AppKeys.ApplyStaticFilesTransformations 
        ? new[] {new StaticFilesPostProcessor()} 
        : new IPostProcessor[] {};
    var transformer = AppKeys.ApplyMinifyingTransformationAndBlockJs
        ? new StyleTransformer(new YuiCssMinifier(), postProcessors)
        : new StyleTransformer(postProcessors);
    transformer.CombineFilesBeforeMinification = AppKeys.ApplyMinifyingTransformationAndBlockJs;

    lessStyles.Transforms.Add(transformer);

    bundles.Add(lessStyles);
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work as I want it to. `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` should be `true` for the file transformation to work but in that case the files are always combined into one.

Is there an way to state explicitly that I want transformations to be enabled, but files should not be combined?

Answer (score 0):

Bundling and minification occurs according to the value of `debug` attribute of `compilation` element in **Web.config**.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Having it enabled renders the files as they are and when `debug="false"` the files are bundled and minified.

So, remove the explicit optimizations, namely remove the line

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = AppKeys.ApplyMinifyingTransformationAndBlockJs || 
        AppKeys.ApplyStaticFilesTransformations;
```

And remember to change the value of `debug` attribute to `false` when deploying the application in production.

More info here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't help in the slightest. First of all, I believe that it is more transparent for that setting to be one of the many keys in the `appSettings` section, just because of how our transformation files are written. Second, no matter where exactly that setting is set, it does not change how the system behaves: with `debug="true"` I get neither transformation nor minification, otherwise I get both of them. This is not a way to avoid combining files into one while applying the desired transformations.